# Need help for text wrap in a colum for desktop and mobile

Tags: php, html, css

I am using this PHP code inserted in the html for displaying the data from the database –

```
<?php
    $des=  str_replace( "\'","'", $row["description"]);
    echo $des;
?>
```

The format used at the backend is MSO with tables , now the data is been displayed on both the desktop and in the mobile. But the mobile display the contents are going out of the box. Would like it to be displayed within the box in the mobile.

Can any one know how to go about his.

Comment: Please show the HTML and CSS you're using to display the data. (Also, you can use the `stripslashes()` PHP function to replace your `str_replace()` function.)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be purely front-end. For example, in CSS set `word-wrap: break-word;` to the container of your content.

---

By the way, it's not the source of your issue, but you might consider using `stripslashes($row["description"])` instead of `str_replace( "\'","'", $row["description"]);`, [see documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: I tried this -stripslashes($row["description"]) , but it did not work